# Laravel - If has errors on validation, insert class in the specifics inputs

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5.1

I'm totally noob in PHP, but my question is, after the validation which has errors for specific inputs, how can I insert a class in the specific input?

Example, if i have this error in the validation: "The email field is required."

How can i insert a specific class in the email input?

Login routes:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'Admin\AdminController@index');

    Route::get('login', 'Admin\AuthController@getLogin');
    Route::post('login', 'Admin\AuthController@postLogin');
    Route::get('logout', 'Admin\AuthController@getLogout');
});
```

AdminController:

```
class AdminController extends AdminBaseController
{

    public function index()
    {
        if(Auth::user()){
            return view('admin/pages/admin/index');
        }

        return view('admin/pages/login/index');
    }

}
```

AuthController:

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{

    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    private $redirectTo = '/admin';

    public $loginPath = '/admin';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);
    }

    public function getLogin()
    {
        if(Auth::user()){
            return redirect('/admin');
        }

        return view('admin/pages/login/index');
    }

    public function postLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|min:6',
        ]);
    }
}
```

My blade form:

```
<form class="s-form" role="form" method="POST" action="/admin/login">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <div class="s-form-item text">
        <input type="text" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="s-form-item text">
        <input type="password" name="password" value="{{ old('password') }}" placeholder="Senha">
    </div>
    <div class="s-form-item">
        @if ($errors->has())
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                    {{ $error }}<br>
                @endforeach
            </div>
        @endif
    </div>
    <div class="s-form-item s-btn-group s-btns-right">
        <input class="s-btn" type="submit" value="Entrar">
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass an argument to the [`has`](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Contracts/Support/MessageBag.html#method_has) method to specify the specific key.

For example, for your email input...

```
<input class="@if($errors->has('email')) some-class @endif" ... >
```

I left out the rest of the input field for brevity. It basically checks if an error for the email input exists. If so, 'some-class' is outputted. Otherwise, it skips over it.

Edit: To answer the question on how you can customize where to output your error messages, you can use the [`get`](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Contracts/Support/MessageBag.html#method_get) or [`first`](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Contracts/Support/MessageBag.html#method_first) methods in conjunction with the `has` method. For example...

```
@if ($errors->has('email'))
    @foreach ($errors->get('email') as $error)
    <p>{{ $error }}</p>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

The `has` method has already been explained. The `get` method retrieves the validation errors. Because there can be more than one validation error, you must loop through it and output it.

In the next example, I use `first`. This method just outputs the first error message so there is no need to loop through it.

```
@if ($errors->has('email'))
<p>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</p>
@endif
```

Comment: Yeah, but it print just all the errors with `$errors->all()`, I want to print the specific errors bellow the specifics inputs... Got it?

Comment: You should specify that in your question then. Lol. There's no mention of that. I'll edit my answer in regards to your second question.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry by my mistake... =)